# Chat UI for ionic3 with dialog flow

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, ionic-framework, dialogflow-es

I've created a chat interface whenever I send messages to dialog flow or receive messages from dialog flow they appear on the left side of the screen. I want my messages to be on the right side & dialog flow messages on the left side & both chat bubbles should of different colors. I have no idea how to differentiate them. Can someone help me?
This is my HTML code.

```
<ion-content>
  <div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;">7 minutes ago</div>
  <div class="msgbubble" *ngFor="let msg of messages">
    <div class="innermsg">
      {{ msg }}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-input placeholder="Type here" [(ngModel)]="question" type="text"></ion-input>
    <ion-buttons right>
      <button ion-button clear icon-only id="sendicon" (click)="ask(question)">
        <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

This is ts code.

```
ask(question) {
    try {
      this.messages.push(question);
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.Access_token)
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      let postParams = {
       "lang": "en",
      "query": question ,
      "sessionId": "12345",
      "timezone": "America/New_York"
      }

      try{
      this.http.post("https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910", postParams, options)
        .subscribe(data => {
          let obj = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
          this.answer = obj.result.fulfillment.speech;
          //console.log(data['_body']);
          console.log(this.answer);
          this.messages.push(this.answer);

         }, error => {
          console.log(error);// Error getting the data
        });
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
    }

  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
  }
```

I want the UI should be as a general chat page/bot. Sending messages on right & receiving messages on left.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in your array "messages" need to have an attribute to indicate if the message is question or answer (would be nice if you add the interface of "message" to your question).
in angular you can change css-classes by condition like:

```
<div [className]="condition ? 'example-class' : 'other-class'"></div>
```

Hope that solves your problem!